# How to use gstreamer to filesink videos from IP Camera

Tags: video, camera, ip, gstreamer

Is there a way to dump feed from IP Camera to a media file, say mp4 format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what you recive from your IP camera. If you already get encoded data (e.g. http+mjpeg or rtp+mpeg4/h264) then you can just mux it (e.g. using mp4mux ! filesink).

Comment: I am recieving an H.265 encoding.

Comment: H.265, are you sure? So far this is only a standard proposal and far from being finalized? What camera would that be?

Comment: Excuse me if i am wrong. Its an AXIS P1344 Network Camera i am trying to get the stream from it transcode it into an audio format. The end goal is to implement an HTTP Live Streaming server using Ubuntu

Comment: Use rtspsrc with the ip/port of the camera for h264 video. You can mux it using mp4mux and filesink to store it on disk.

Comment: I finally got stream from IP Camera. I use rtsp as what ensonic advised. The next step now is to transcode it into HLS or any format for live streaming using gstreamer any ideas?

Comment: In the future, please post a new question. Have a look at gst-rtsp-server for relaying it as a rtsp stream. You might also want to look at: http://schleef.org/2012/06/14/gstreamer-streaming-server-library/